# Apache Storm 2.1.0 memory related configurations

Tags: apache-storm, topology, apache-storm-topology, storm-topology, apache-storm-configs

We are in the process of migrating to 2.1.0 from 1.1.x.

In our current setup we have following memory configurations in storm.yaml

```
nimbus.childopts: -Xmx2048m
supervisor.childopts: -Xmx2048m
worker.childopts: -Xmx16384m
```

I see many other memory related configs in https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml, and have following questions regarding them.

1. what is the difference between **worker.childopts** and **topology.worker.childopts**? If we are setting worker.childopts in storm.yaml, do we still have to override **topology.worker.childopts**?
2. If we are setting **worker.childopts** in storm.yaml, do we still have to override **worker.heap.memory.mb**? Is there a relationship between these two configs?
3. Should **topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb** < **worker.childopts**? How should we decide the value of **topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb** ?

Appreciate if someone could explain these points.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently fiddled with some of these configs myself, so I am sharing my insights here:

1. `worker.childopts` vs `topology.worker.childopts` - the first parameter sets childopts for all workers. The second parameter can be used to override those for individual topologies, e.g. by using `conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS, "someJvmArgsHere");`
2. The default value for `worker.childopts` is `"-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:artifacts/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"` according to the [storm git](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml). Pay attention to the first argument, it includes a replacement pattern `%HEAP-MEM%`. This pattern is replaced with whatever you configure for `worker.heap.memory.mb`. You are able to override the latter parameter from inside a topology configuration in Java, thus I guess they build it that way to be able to quickly modify Java heap for individual topologies. One thing I noticed is that, when overriding, storm only seems to make use of the override value if at least one spout or bolt is configured with `.setMemoryLoad(int heapSize)`.
3. this highly depends on the individual topology's needs, but in general it is most likely a very good idea to have `topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb` be smaller than whatever you have configured for -Xmx in `worker.childopts`. How to find a good value for `topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb` is up to testing and knowledge about the memory consumption of your topology's components. For instance, I have a topology which receives tuples from redis and emits them. If bolts are busy, tuples may pile up in the spout, thus I configure it with some headroom in terms of memory. However, I normally do not modify `topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb` but rather use the `setMemoryLoad(int heapSize)` method of a topology's component, as this allows to set different values for individual components of the topology. Storm docs for this and related topics are [here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.2.0/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html).